# Java copy source code from Internet, paste it to Eclipse and run it

Tags: java, eclipse, copy, web

I'm reading an article about visitor pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern . I want to copy java "source file" from this page to eclipse and run it. I want to avoid copying each class separately giving them a name. However java doesn't allow multiple classess in one file. Is it possible in eclipse? What is the best way of solving this problem?

Scheme of code that I want to copy:

```
interface CarElement {
   ...
}

interface CarElementVisitor {
    ...
}

class Car implements CarElement {
    ...
}

...

class CarElementPrintVisitor implements CarElementVisitor {
    ...
}

public class VisitorDemo {
    ...
}
```

Comment: they can all encapsulate inside one big class, e.g. `Main`. You then probably have to make them `public static class`es.

Comment: How many classes are you talking about here? Is it really that onerous to copy/paste each class into its own file?  You should get used to that as it's the way Java is intended to be written.

Comment: When I write project I need sometimes to test new features (eg. arraylist with classes as elements), to see how they work. I don't want to change the code I have. So I make few new classes like (foo{}, bar{}) and try inside of them this new feature. But then I have a mess in my view, I don't know which classes are test ones and which belong to my project.

Comment: That is one of the things packages are for. Make and use a different package for your "sandbox" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether that's what you're looking for, but Java does allow inner classes. Just put all of the classes you copied into one large class:

```
class Main {

    interface CarElement {
       ...
    }

    interface CarElementVisitor {
        ...
    }

    class Car implements CarElement {
        ...
    }

    ...

    class CarElementPrintVisitor implements CarElementVisitor {
        ...
    }

    public class VisitorDemo {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: The classes will need to be declared `static`

Answer (score 0):

Copy a single class's source individually and then paste it into a Java **Source Folder** in the **Package Explorer** View. It will create the relevant file for you.